# Converting items of the list into tuple and then again appending them to the list

Tags: python, loops

I want items of the list `l` to be converted into tuple and then again added into the list.

I am 90% successful but can't change all the items.

Code:

```
l = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]
u=0
y=[ ]
for i in range(4):
         y.append(l[u])
         if u == 3:
               t = tuple(y)
               print(t)
               del l[0:-4]
               l.append(t)
               print(l)

         u+=1
```

Output :

```
(1,2,3,4)
[5,6,7,8,(1,2,3,4)]
```

I want the `5,6,7,8` in the tuple form.

Comment: Can you explain the logic behind the algorithm? That is, why don't you type in `[(5,6,7,8),(1,2,3,4)]`? Do you want to take all chunks of size 4 from the input, put them into tuples, and then reverse their order?

Comment: why are you using the variable `u` when you already have `i`?!

Comment: Yes i want them in the group of 4  and then turn them into tuple and then append them to list back

Comment: @moe assal It's a sample code i have just made so it has some unusual lines.

Comment: @justahuman it is just a piece of code of my project.

Comment: @AyushRaj How do you feel about the current answer? If that is not viable, can you explain why?

Comment: The answer given by @dorukerenaktas is working for me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this code to split you array to `n` sized pieces and add this pieces as tuples in the same list.

```py
lst = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]
n = 4

tuples = [tuple(lst[i:i + 4]) for i in range(0, len(lst), 4)]
print(tuples)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to batch up the values of the list into tuples, using slices is the easiest way. You can get batches of 4 by doing something like this:

```
batches = []
for i in range(0, len(l), 4):
    batch = l[i:i+4] #get l[i] through l[i+4]
    batches.append(batch)
```

Now all you need to do is turn each batch into a tuple, which you can do with the tuple function:

```
batches = []
for i in range(0, len(l), 4):
    batch = tuple(l[i:i+4]) #get l[i] through l[i+4]
    batches.append(batch)
```

Now the `batches` variable will contain the list you want. If you need that in `l`, just assign batches to l like this:

```
l = batches
```

It's generally not a good idea to modify a list while you are iterating through it if you can help it, as it will make iteration more complex unnecessarily. That's why I initialize a separate list for keeping track of the output list.

Answer (score 0):

TL;DR
use:

```
total_list = l[:4] + [(tuple(l[4:]))]
```

If you want to turn a list into a tuple simply use

```
my_tup = tuple(my_list)
```

if you want only part of the list you can access it using `:`
for example the first four elements of a list are:

```
first_four = my_list[0:4] 
# or in short notation
first_four = my_list[:4]
```

also to append to a list use `my_list.append(some_item)`

So in total we have:

```
l = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]
total_list = l[:4]
total_list.append(tuple(l[4:]))
```